# What is the difference between gradient and imgradient?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to compute gradient of image I. I have two options that are

```
[Gx, Gy] = gradient(I);
g = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
```

and

```
[g,~] = imgradient(I, 'sobel');
```

My question are

1. What is gradient method using in first option?
2. What is befinet of finding gradient using sobel method ?

Thank all

This is what I tried

```
I=zeros([128 128]);
I(50:100,50:100)=100;
[Gx, Gy] = gradient(I);
g1 = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
[g2,~] = imgradient(I, 'sobel');
subplot(121);imshow(g1,[]);title('First option')
subplot(122);imshow(g2,[]);title('Second option')
```

[image]

When noisy is added to image, the different will be more clear

```
I=zeros([128 128]);
I(50:100,50:100)=100;
%% Add noise image;
noiseStd=5;
I_noise = I + (noiseStd * randn([128, 128]));
[Gx, Gy] = gradient(I_noise);
g1 = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
[g2,~] = imgradient(I_noise, 'sobel');
subplot(121);imshow(g1,[]);title('First option')
subplot(122);imshow(g2,[]);title('Second option')
```

[image]

As visualization, the second option provided more brightness value

Comment: Have you tried comparing? The amin difference is that one comes in a toolbox for images, the other works for any surface

Comment: Yes. I updated it. Please see my updated question

Comment: Hi! consider accepting an answer as valid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is the 'Sobel' operator indeed. The sobel operator is a matrix that is convoluted with the image to compute its directional gradients.

The sobel operator is defined as (from wikipedia):

[image]

while what `gradient` does is just directional differences. You can interpret this as gradient doing

```
Gx=[ 0 0 0;                Gx=[ 0 -1 0;
    -1 0 1;         and         0  0 0;
     0 0 0]                     0  1 0];
```

This difference is because when one has an image, it is know that it is a discretization of a continuous domain. The Sobel operator helps to take into account things that happen "around" the given pixel.

Comment: So, if i only regard the gradient without its direction as my above code. What is different between these ]two gradients?

Comment: @user8430 `imgradient` just gives `sqrt(Gx^2+Gy^2)` as output, while `gradient` gives you separatedly. just that.

Comment: From my result, it clears to show that central difference method results in more noise than Sobel method. Thus, Compared to the central difference method, Sobel method achieves better noise rejection using a different kernel with coefficients designed. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @user8430 yes, of course. Because it takes into account not only the 2 neighbours of the pixel, but 6, therefore the noise gets a bit  "averaged out"

Comment: @user8430 great answers, but to add to what Ander said "the noise gets a bit averaged out" Notice Sobel is also weighted more heavily in the center. This acts almost like a (low resolution) Gaussian smoothing filter. A prewitt filter (true average) will use `Gy = [1,1,1;0,0,0;-1,-1,-1]` and although this will remove some amount of noise, the result is different than sobel. Think of these filters as being preconvolved. Made of an edge detector `[1,0,-1] * smoothing_function` So just think of the difference between an average blur and a gaussian blur. Hope that gives a little more insight

Answer (score 8):

[**`gradient`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) exclusively uses **central differences** and [**`imgradient`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html) gives you a choice, e.g. `'central'` as well or the default `'sobel'`. Using the first option `imgradient` looks the same as `gradient`:

```
I=zeros([128 128]);
I(50:100,50:100)=100;
%% Add noise image;
noiseStd=5;
I_noise = I + (noiseStd * randn([128, 128]));
[Gx, Gy] = gradient(I_noise);
g1 = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
[g2,~] = imgradient(I_noise, 'sobel');
[g3,~] = imgradient(I_noise, 'central');
subplot(131);imshow(g1,[]);title('gradient')
subplot(132);imshow(g2,[]);title('imgradient sobel')
subplot(133);imshow(g3,[]);title('imgradient central')
```

[image]

---

For `imgradient` there are five options available:

- 'sobel'  Sobel gradient operator (default)
- 'prewitt'    Prewitt gradient operator
- 'central' Central difference gradient: dI/dx = (I(x+1) - I(x-1))/2
- 'intermediate'Intermediate difference gradient: dI/dx = I(x+1) - I(x)
- ‘roberts'    Roberts gradient operator

While the documentation explaines:

> The algorithmic approach taken in `imgradient` for each of the listed
>   gradient methods is to first compute directional gradients, `Gx` and `Gy`,
>   with respect to the x-axis and y-axis. The x-axis is defined along the
>   columns going right and the y-axis is defined along the rows going
>   down. The gradient magnitude and direction are then computed from
>   their orthogonal components `Gx` and `Gy`.

Comment: Thank for your example of central difference. So, what is befinet of sobel operator. As Piglet said that it provides more smooth image.

Comment: @user8430 The answer would be behind the scope of StackOverflow, and I actually don't know it. You'll need to do some research on the single algorithms.